# Why can't I get my image aspectfit on rotated view of android emulator

Tags: xamarin, rotation, emulation, landscape, aspect

I'm a beginner with Xamarin and my code is very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarineTest2"
             x:Class="XamarineTest2.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Image BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               Source="Juice.jpg"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

With the basic android emulator debugger on my visual studio 2017,
I get aspectfit image on portrait(vertical) view as expected like below.
[enter image description here][1]
But when I rotate it to landscape(horizontal) view using the button on the emulator,
I get aspectfill-like image as shown below.
[enter image description here][2]
How can I keep it aspectfit on landscape view which means the bottom of the image should not be cut off?

Thank you guys in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddseU.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hdDS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I found everything works fine if I use Grid instead of StackLayout. I don't know why, but there seems to be more such problem with StackLayout. Plz add more comment for anyone having a similar problem, since this issue is kind of very basic one in Xamarin.